# How do I fill an array of random uppercase letters as a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, random, fill

I'm trying to write a function to fill an array with 40 random uppercase letters. I attempted to fill the array and print it but I'm not getting any output.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fillS1(char y[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
char s1[40];
int n;

fillS1(&s1[40]);

for (n = 0; n < 41; n++) {
    printf("%s", s1);
}


return 0;
}

void fillS1(char y[40]){

int x = 1;

while (x < 41) {
    x = rand() % 26;
    x = 2 + 'A';
    x = y[x];
    x++;
}


}
```

Comment: Use `printf("%s\n", s1);` to print `s1`.

Comment: Considering `'A'` is 65 on most systems, you're probably going out of bounds very quickly seeing as how you add 2 to that and then use it as the index in a length 40 array. Even if `x` just had the values of the loop, you're still starting at 1 and going to 40 when arrays start at 0 and go to n-1.

Comment: And you're immediately throwing away that lovely rand() you generated. Well, maybe not-so-lovely and not-so-rand, as srand() is never called.

Comment: Basile, I took your advice and my output was: /n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n/n (ect).

Comment: It is a backslash \ not a slash `/`

Comment: Your while loop makes no sense because of using `x` for different things.

Comment: `fillS1(&s1[40]);` -- why pass a pointer to the end of the array? That's wrong.

Comment: `int x = 1;` -- This is wrong -- C uses 0-indexing. Don't you have an instructor, or a text, or existing C code to learn from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just code

```
void fill_string_40(char str[])
{
   for (int i=0; i<40; i++)
     str[i] = 'A' + random() % 26;
   str[40] = (char)0; // (char)0 is equal to use '\0'
}
```

and use it as (e.g. in your `main`)

```
{ char s[41];
  fill_string_40(s);
  printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Notice that you need an extra byte for the null terminating character. Ad we are assuming some ASCII compatible char encoding. A more portable way could have been

```
str[i] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random() % 26];
```

since literal strings are constant arrays of chars.

If you code in C++, see the [standard `<random>` header file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). If you code for Linux, see [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) and [getrandom(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html), perhaps use it with [srandom(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/srandom.3.html). Read also about the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)

Comment: Why use 42 when storing 41 values? Actually 42 makes sense if storing 41 values as the OP does, but you only store 40.

Comment: `Because 42 is even` -- I have no idea why that's relevant. `I would made it a multiple of 8 (the size of a word)` -- nor that. Make it what the requirements and logic demand of it.

Comment: "I'm declaring s of size 48 because that is usually a multiple of the word size" -- What the heck does that have to do with anything? The compiler is perfectly capable of aligning things for efficiency if there's some point to it.

Comment: This is perfect, but it doesn't need to be printed 40 times. lol.

Comment: It is not printed 40 times, the calling block is supposed to be e.g. in the `main`

Comment: @user1681673 I LOL at your misreading of the code. It's not perfect because `str` contains lowercase letters.

Comment: Use char literals, 'A' and 'Z' and something like ('Z'-'A') in this case, instead of numbers, it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: I printed your code and it printed 40 lines of 40 random characters. I didn't misread the code, I read the output.

Comment: My code does not contain any `main` function (I left that up to you) so cannot be compiled into an executable. What did you put into *your* `main` function?? How did you call my `fill_string_40` from your code?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was your code. But yeah, I called it in main. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it, Basile.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, and don't forget to call srand() in the beginning of your program somewhere, ONCE.

```
void fillRand(char ar[], size_t len)
{
    size_t i=0;
    if (0 == len)
        return;

    for (i=0;i<(len-1);++i)
       ar[i] = (rand() % 26) + 'A';
    ar[len-1] = 0;
}
```

BTW, totally not portable, as the spec does not call for 'A'..'Z' to be either sequential or contiguous, but it will probably work fine for what you need. If absolute portability was required, then the following will *always* work:

```
void fillRand(char ar[], size_t len)
{
    static const char a[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    size_t i=0;

    if (0 == len)
        return;

    for (i=0;i<(len-1);++i)
       ar[i] = a[ (rand() % (sizeof(a)-1)) ];
    ar[len-1] = 0;
}
```

Will work on both normal and EBCDIC platforms. (if you don't know the difference, just use this one).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should pass address of first char while calling `fillS1()`. Replace `fillS1(&s1[40]);` with `fillS1(&s1[0]);`